# Comparison of CDFs

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, which take values between $0$ and $1$. Both $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same expression of the CDF, but for different values of a parameter $p \in [0,1]$ on which the CDF depends. I do not have any information about their probability density function. Both $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same mean $\mu$, but have different variances $V_1$ (calculated at $p_1$) and $V_2$ (calculated at $p_2$), respectively. I know that $V_1 < V_2$ for $p_1 < p_2$.

I am unable to prove that, for  $\theta < \mu$, 
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1 > \theta) > \mathbb{P}(X_2 > \theta).$$
Please note that $\theta \in (0,1)$.

On the contrary, if $\theta > \mu$, I would like to prove that
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1 > \theta) < \mathbb{P}(X_2 > \theta).$$
Intuitively, I can see that these are the cases. But, I would prefer a mathematical proof. I tried using Chebyshev inequality with no luck.

Comment: If this statement holds (I am not sure if it does), then you need to replace strict inequality with $\ge$.

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are functions of the same parameter $p$. The values of variances $V_1$ and $V_2$ correspond to two different values of $p$, i.e., $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively. I know that $V_1 < V_2$ if $p_1 < p_2$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true. Take $X_1 = \frac{1}{4}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and $X_1 = \frac{3}{4}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Take $X_2$ uniform on $[0,1]$. Note that indeed $V_1 = \frac{1}{16}<\frac{1}{12}=V_2$, while $\mu=\frac{1}{2}$ for both. $\mathbb{P}(X_1 > 0.3)=\frac{1}{2}<0.7=\mathbb{P}(X_2 > 0.3)$.

Comment: I think this is will be true of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables. In my case, they depend on a parameter. Basically, they correspond to two different values of that parameter.

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ satisfy all assumptions in your question.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I should have given more information about $X_1$ and $X_2$. I have edited the question.

Comment: Introducing a parameter does not destroy this example. Take $F(x;p) = 1_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}(p)F_{X_1}(x) + 1_{(\frac{1}{2}, 1]}(p)F_{X_2}(x)$, with $1$ the indicator function and $F$ the respective CDFs, and take $p_1=0$ and $p_2 = 1$.