# Comparison of CDF for different variances

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Note: This question is similar to [Comparison of CDFs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965283/comparison-of-cdfs). But, I asked it there in a wrong way. I am correcting it here. Sorry for the redundancy.

I have a random variable $X$, which has mean $\mu$. The variance of $X$ depends on a parameter $p \in [0,1]$. Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be two values of $p$. I know that, if $p_1 < p_2$ the variance correpsonding to $p_1$ (say $V_1$) is smaller than that corresponding to $p_2$ (say $V_2$), i.e., $V_1 < V_2$.

Under this scenario, I would like to prove that, when $x < \mu$, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(X > x)|_{p_1} > \mathbb{P}(X > x)|_{p_2},$$
where $\mathbb{P}(X > x)|_{p_1}$ denotes that the probability is to be calculated when $p = p_1$, i.e., when variance is $V_1$. The expression of CDF is too complex to compare for different variances.

To illustrate the question in a better way, I would like to provide the following figure, where we assume that the curves represent the probability density function (PDF) of $X$ for different values of $p$ (expression of PDF is not known).

[image]

The green curve has the largest variance, while the red one has the smallest variance. From this figure, we can see that, if $x = \mu - 1$ (i.e., $x < \mu$), the red curve will have higher $\mathbb{P}(X > x)$ than that for the green curve. Similarly, if $x = \mu + 1$, the green curve will have the higher $\mathbb{P}(X > x)$ than that for red curve. The corresponding CDF looks like as below:

[image]

I would also like to prove that all curves of CDF intersect at the mean $\mu$ as seen in second figure.

Comment: Probably you are making more assumptions than you stated. From the last graph, all of them has the same median at the mean, and they looks like a family of continuous unimodal symmetric distribution.

Comment: Do you mean that the things I want to prove may not hold in general? For example, is it not necessary that curves of CDFto intersect at the mean?